# setMyLocationEnabled is not working in ionic 2

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, ionic-framework

In this code I try to find a way to show `my location button` but still the same result.

```
loadMap() {
    this.Geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((position) => {
      let latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
      let mapOptions = {
        center: latLng,
        zoom: 15,
        MyLocationEnabled: true,
        setMyLocationButtonEnabled: true,
        zoomControl: false,
        disableDefaultUI: true,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,              
      }      
      this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapElement.nativeElement, mapOptions);
  this.addMarker();
    }, (err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  }
```

as you can see below :

[image]